# Read XDocument same name elements using foreach

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file:

```
<encounter type="type1">
<strings>
    <text>Text1</text>
    <text>Text2</text>
    <text>Text3</text>
</strings>
</encounter>
```

Idea is put all values of text elements into List if "type" attribute is correct. My code is:

```
foreach (XElement el in xDoc.Root.Elements())
{
    if(el.Attribute("type").Value == choice)
    {
        List<string> textStrings = new List<string>();

        foreach (XElement elStr in el.Element("strings")) {
            textStrings.Add(elStr.Element("text").Value);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Part with attribute is working, but read several elements wits same name is tricky for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `foreach`:

```
    foreach (XElement elStr in el.Element("strings")) {
        foreach(XElement elText in elStr.Elements("text")) {
            textStrings.Add((string)elText);
        }
    }
```

Or to make it more clear:

```
List<string> textStrings = xDoc.Root
                               .Elements()
                               .First(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == choice)
                               .Element("strings")
                               .Elements("text").
                               .Select(t => (string)t)
                               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant of code works well for my task:

```
foreach (XElement el in xDoc.Root.Elements())
    {
        if(el.Attribute("type").Value == choice)
        {
            XElement elStr = el.Element("strings");                
            foreach (XElement elText in elStr.Elements("text"))
            {
                textStrings.Add((string)elText);
            }      
            break;
        }
    }
```